# How to delete from a database using AJAX/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

This code is within my view template:

```
@foreach ($comment as $text)

{{Form::open(array('method'=>'DELETE', 'route' => array('story.destroy', $text->id)))}}
     {{ Form::submit('Delete')}}
{{ Form::close() }}

@endforeach


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).parent().attr('action');
        $.ajax(url);
    }
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{        

   Post::find($id)->destroy();

}
```

I've been for sometime trying to delete a row from my Post table without page refresh using JQUERY and with no success. If any one can help me find a solution I would be very grateful?